# Return only a json object to ajax caller

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I'd like to return/access just an array on my `success` callback.
But I only get the whole html page.

```
$.ajax({
  'URL': 'getData.php',
  success:function(data){
    alert(data); //Whole html file
  }
})
```

#### getData.php

```
<?php
 //Feed the array with database content

 echo json_encode( $columns );

?>
```

How may I access the just the content of `$columns`

Obs1: My php file contains ONLY php code, 100%.

This is what is printed with `alert` above:

[image: alert]

Comment: send only the columns, or send array that first element is the columns and second element is the html

Comment: No idea how to send only the `$columns` or the second thing you said =\ Any tips ?

Comment: what you mean by whole html file? what is column data look like?

Comment: make sure you php file contains only php code and no html code. in the jQuery ajax set the data type and in the success block parse the return value to json object which will conver data into javascript objects

Comment: Updated the question. My php file that ajax is redirected to is 100% php code. Also added a print with what is shown by alert

Comment: @PlayHardGoPro you are not returning only php, or only columns, because it shows you have html in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have to set the dataType, and put url without single quotes.

Try to do this...

```
 $.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET', 
    url: 'getData.php', 
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) { 
        $.each(data, function(index, element) {
            /* Operate with each array row */
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Actually it worked. Now it prints the results like `result1, result2, result3`

Comment: with element.name he can access to the json fields

Answer (score 1):

Your script is has HTML which cannot be parsed so make sure it returns only json string.

I know what do you mean, you can parse the json in javascript which was sent by PHP using JSON.parse(string);

Make sure your php doesn't return any other string or HTML other than encoded json.

Here is your modified JS, It should work as intended, You can check your desired output in browser console.

```js
$.ajax({
  'URL': 'getData.php',
  success:function(data){
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(data);
    alert(data); //Whole html file
  }
})
```